# Efficient SVG resizing in Chromium within javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance, svg

I wonder which may be the most efficient way to resize/scale an SVG-image, within the browser dynamically. Currently I'm loading the image with this code:

HTML:

```
<img id="test" src="images/test.svg" />
```

javascript:

```
var image=$("#test");
        var x=0;
        var ref = setInterval(function(){
            image.attr("width",x);
            if (x<500){
              x=x+1;
            }
            else{
              clearInterval(ref);
            }
        },100);
```

This causes the cpu to be more than 10% Quadcore i7.
The SVG doesn't contain any transformations. So I think that's a lot of computing for only rendering an svg. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks Dan.

Comment: Changing the width means that the svg potentially has to re-resolve percentage values and font-sizes inside the svg. Using a transform on the img element should help with avoiding that. See http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css3/animations/zoom-transform.html for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS

```
#test {
  transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
}
```

Comment: I want to call it within javascript.

Comment: So make it a a class and use `element.classList.add('scale')` or the like

Comment: and you think this is the most efficient way to resize the .svg? My CPU-Load is on 35%.